# How do I print out java debugging information to the screen like gdb's print command in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I use the gdb debugger in c++ eclipse I can open up the console tab and type  `p someVar` and it will print out the value of that variable.  Now I'm in java eclipse and I would like to do the same type of thing but I can't find out how.  I know there is a variables tab but I would like to use print because of its ability to print out function calls and such.  Does anyone know if java has this debugging ability or am I stuck constantly using the Variables tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Display view](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm). You can also select any code in your editor (where you are currently debugging), right click -> watch, and it will appear in your watched expressions.